# React Dynamically Fetch component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

```
<CustomMainContainer>
        <Header />
        <SectionContainer>
          <SectionInfo title="CovidTrackeReact">
            <button className="text-nav-color text-nav p-button w-button text-center shadow-button rounded-button">
              <Link to="/about">Learn More</Link>
            </button>
          </SectionInfo>
        </SectionContainer>
      </CustomMainContainer>
      <CardContainer />
      <Footer />
```

How can i put this structure into App.tsx so that when i change a route, only the SectionInfo  and CardContainer  changes ?
For example:

```
<li className="inline p-nav-25">
          <Link to="/summary">Summary</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="inline p-nav-25">
          <Link to="/dayone">Day One</Link>
        </li>
```

```
        <Route exact path="/summary" component={SummaryPage} />
```

I click on summary and i should render
Clicking on the Summary should render the content of the SummaryPage instead of the CardContainer and change the value of the SectionInfo (the last one should be easy).

App.tsx

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
        <Route exact path="/summary" component={SummaryPage} />
        <Route exact path="/rank/total" component={TotalCases} />
        <Route exact path="/rank/daily" component={DailyCases} />
        <Route exact path="/dayone" component={DayOne} />
        <Route exact path="/live/after/date" component={LiveAfterDate} />
        <Route exact path="/live/daily/country" component={LiveDailyCountry} />
        <Route exact path="/live/total" component={LiveTotal} />

        <Route exact path="/country/total" component={CountryTotalPage} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/country/status/dates"
          component={CountryStatusBetweenDate}
        />
        <Route exact path="/country/status" component={CountryStatus} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/country/cases/dates"
          component={CountryCasesBetweenDate}
        />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={ContactPage} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

EDIT

```
<Router>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <CustomMainContainer>
          <Header />
          <SectionContainer>
            <SectionInfo title="CovidTrackeReact">
              <button className="text-nav-color text-nav p-button w-button text-center shadow-button rounded-button">
                Learn more
              </button>
            </SectionInfo>
          </SectionContainer>
        </CustomMainContainer>
        {routes.routes.map(({ component, title, children, url }) => (
          <Route exact path={url} component={component} title={title} />
        ))}
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Router>
```

It seems it wasnt that hard and this does the trick with an array having the configs and maping it. But anyone knows how i can pass a title and child into SectionInfo  whithout messing the layout ? cant map SectionInfo but i would like to change the title and the "button" based on my route ? So sectioninfo would have a different title and button based on the route.

route config:

```
import DayOne from "../Pages/DayOnePage/DayOne";
import CardContainer from "../Pages/LandingPage_/CardContainer";
import SummaryPage from "../Pages/SummaryPage/SummaryPage";
const routes: any[] = [];

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default {
  routes: [
    {
      component: CardContainer,
      url: "/",
      title: "Landing Page",
      children: "Test",
    },
    {
      component: SummaryPage,
      url: "/summary",
      title: "Summary Page",
      children: "Test",
    },
    {
      component: DayOne,
      url: "/dayone",
      title: "Day One Page",
      children: "Test",
    },
  ],
};
```

Section Info:

```
export default function SectionInfo(props: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-contentTitle text-nav-color font-content">
        {props.title}
      </h1>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The last example you posted is exactly what you should do. Is there something not working? What is the problem? Can you post App.tsx? Have you followed the [react-router docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)?

Comment: The thing is the custommaincontainer is on my landing page and i want to move it to App.tsx but i dont know how i should do that.